# Skip first/opener image in gallery in magnific-popup

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

How do I skip the first image in a Gallery, I don't want it to be part of the images that is shown in the lightbox.

```
<div class="gallery">
<a href="path-to-image.jpg">Open image 1 (gallery #2)</a>
<a href="path-to-image.jpg">Open image 2 (gallery #2)</a>
</div>

$('.gallery').each(function() { // the containers for all your galleries
$(this).magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a', // the selector for gallery item
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
      enabled:true
    }
  });
});
```

So how can I exlude "Open image 1 (gallery #2)" from the pop up?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Magnific Popup data-mfp-src attribute to set the source of the image to be shown to your second image.

A.jpg is the first image that will show after a user selects start.jpg. start.jog will never show up in the gallery.

```html
<a href="_/img/start.jpg" data-mfp-src="_/img/A.jpg"><img src="_/img/start.jpg"></a>
<a href="_/img/A.jpg" data-mfp-src="_/img/B.jpg"><img src="_/img/A.jpg"></a>
<a href="_/img/B.jpg" data-mfp-src="_/img/C.jpg"><img src="_/img/B.jpg"></a>
<a href="_/img/C.jpg" data-mfp-src="_/img/D.jpg"><img src="_/img/C.jpg"></a>
<a href="_/img/D.jpg" data-mfp-src="_/img/E.jpg"><img src="_/img/D.jpg"></a>
```